# tryCatch in for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, try-catch

I am having issues running a `tryCatch` statement within a for loop. I want to go through each row in my data frame (`x`) and if there is an error in taking the sqrt of  the given row in column `k1` I want `sqrtd` to equal `"NULL"` and if not error to be the sqrt value.

Below is the code I have tried, however the new column `sqr` for every row has `"NULL"` but only the second row should be `"NULL"` since one can't take the `sqrt("a")`.

```
library(Jmisc)
library(dplyr)

x <- data.frame(k1 = c(3,"a",3,4,5), k2 = c(1,NA,NA,4,5), data1 = 1:5)
p <- data.frame(NULL)

for (row in 1:nrow(x)){
  sqrtd <- tryCatch(sqrt(x$k1[row]),error=function(e) sqrtd = "NULL")

  x <- addCol(x,value=c(sqr=sqrtd))
  p <- rbind(p,x) 
}

print(p)
```

Comment: Ok so hypothetically if x$k1 had the same type and there was an error thrown in the second row, would Konrad's answer work?

Answer (score 0):

JMisc’s [`addCol`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/Jmisc/versions/0.3.1/topics/addCol) seems to add a single value (the documentation confusingly calls it “constant”) to the data.frame for the whole column. In your code, you are replacing the existing column after the first iteration with the new value.

A solution in your case is to avoid the `for` loop — in fact, data.frames should virtually never be built inside a loop. Instead, use R’s vectorised operations. Such as:

```
sqrt_or_null = function (x) {
    tryCatch(sqrt(x), error = function (e) "NULL")
}

p = mutate(x, sqr = lapply(k1, sqrt_or_null))
```

However, this will leave you with a list column, which is an unwieldy data type in a data.frame. The reason is that a given non-list column can only contain values of a single type, but your function returns *different* types depending on whether the operation succeeds or not: either `numeric` or `character`.

You could cast the results:

```
p = mutate(x, sqr = as.character(lapply(k1, sqrt_or_null)))
```

… but I suggest thinking about a better representation of failed values (such as `NA`), or to avoid failures before performing this operation (e.g. by `filter`ing invalid rows).

Your code has an additional issue: `k1`’s type is `factor`, not `numeric`. So it will fail for *every* value. You will need to convert the factor values to numeric values first, which requires two steps: conversion to character strings, and then to numeric values:

```
p = x %>%
    mutate(k1num  = as.numeric(as.character(k1))) %>%
    mutate(sqr = ifelse(is.na(k1num), "NULL", sqrt(k1num)))
```

Comment: @MLS It does, but the reason is that your column is actually a column of *character strings* (or rather, factors), not numbers. (See edited answer)

Comment: Ok thanks that makes sense. I am just trying to understand tryCatch better, because this is just an example however in my final code I am not using sqrt I am using a function from a package.

Answer (score 0):

Every vector can only be of one type (e.g., numeric, logical, character). If you try to include more than one type in a vector assignment, the vector will be coerced into the broadest type that can handle the inputs. If you run `x$k1`, you should notice that the resulting vector is a character vector of strings (i.e., `"3" "a" "3" "4" "5"`). This is because `"a"` is a string, so the whole vector `x$k1` is coerced to character. Taking the square root of any element in this vector will yield an error, so `sqrtd` always gets assigned `"NULL"`.